# How can I check QueryHint work or not?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA allows placing `@QueryHints` annotation on the interface method and can be applied to the methods annotated with `@Query` and without such.

```
@QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="50"))
List<Foo> findAll();
```

How can I check know for sure that hint was honored?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Why do you want to do that, you should be testing your own code, not Spring Data JPA (which is what you are doing when trying to verify that).

Comment: Just debug the code that applies query hints.